# How do I create a new txt file from another file which is a list?

Tags: sed, cat

I'm trying to create a second config file from a file with a list of domains.

File1 (file1.txt) contents

```
example.com  
example.org  
example.net  
.
.
.
```

I want to automatically create this second file (file2.txt) with the contents like this.

```
blahblahblah /something/example.com  /something/exmaple.org  /something/example.net......
```

Seems simple enough but I can't figure it out.  I'm able to make a list of domains (file1.txt) and I just need to create this second file which I'll be using as part of a config file.

Comment: It's not quite clear what the real problem is. The example looks incorrect.

Comment: If we know what format the configuration file uses, we could solve this properly by outputting it in the correct form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With sed

```
sed -n '
    s,^,/something/,
    1s/^/blahblahblah /
    H
    ${g;s/\n/ /gp}
' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

with bash

```
(   printf "blahblahblah" 
    mapfile -t lines < file1.txt
    printf " /something/%s" "${lines[@]}"
    echo 
) > file2.txt
```

or

```
{   printf "blahblahblah" 
    while IFS= read -r line; do printf " /something/%s" "$line"; done < file1.txt
    echo 
} > file2.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

**`awk`** approach:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ printf "blahblahblah" }{ printf " /something/%s", $0 }
     END{ print "" }' file1.txt > file2.txt
```